# The uniqueness of the Division Theorem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The Division Theorem states, that
$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{Z},b\neq0\colon\exists!q,r\in\mathbb{Z}\colon a=qb+r,0\le r<\vert b\vert$$
Usually, the proofs are divided into two parts: First a proof of the existence of these numbers and then a proof of their uniqueness. Looking at the (not formalized) proof: Considering
$$...,a-3b,a-2b,a-b,a,a+b,a+2b,a+3b,..$$
Selecting the smallest non-negative member of this sequence gives us an $r$ fulfilling the defining inequality and also gives us $q$ in terms of $r$ through the equality $r=a-qb$. This finishes the existence proof and then the uniqueness is shown using contradiction. However I don't understand why that is necessary.
Considering that $b\neq0$ we can say that $q_1\neq q_2\Rightarrow q_1b\neq q_2b$ and hence $a-q_1b\neq a-q_2b$ for any $q_1,q_2$. We conclude that all the elements of the sequence above are distinct. Choosing a least non-negative element of the sequence implies the Well-ordering principle is assumed.
It states that every subset of positive integers contains a least element, an element $s$ of the set $S$ so that $s\le x$ for all $x\in S$. When all elements are distinct however we know that no other $x=s$ exists, so the inequality becomes strict. This in turn implies the uniqueness of this least element, the uniqueness of $r$ and by $r=a-qb$ the uniqueness of $q$.
I would like to know whether the above reasoning is wrong and/or why the proof of the uniqueness using contradiction seems to always be included (I would consider observing that all elements are distinct easier and shorter than the whole contradiction proof).

Comment: To add to the answer that was already posted : it boils down to this: when you give a constructive existence proof, you use a method of construction. Maybe at some point in your construction you see that there is a unique element satisfying your construction and you may be tempted to say that it proves the uniqueness of the object having the desired property. However, an object satisfying said property need not be obtained by said construction (unless you can prove it); so doing a separate proof for uniqueness is necessary.

Comment: For uniqueness we need not only that the sequence elements are distinct but, rather, that they are at least distance $b$ apart (since their difference is divisible by $b).\,$ Thus any interval of length $b$ contains at most one element of the sequence. If we increase the remainder bound then remainders are no longer unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have found $q$ and $0\leq r<b$ such that
$$a=bq+r$$
and this $r$ is characterized as the smallest non-negative element in the set $S=\{a-bq\mid q\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.

The uniquenss of $r$ as the smallest positive element of $S$ is not enough. You also have to check that there is no other non-negative $s\in S$ with $0\leq s<b$ (such an $s$ need **not** be the smallest one).

Ultimately, the proof boils down to showing that if $s\in S$ and $s>r$, then $s\geq r+b>b$ (so the inequality $0\leq s<b$ can't hold). You can't avoid this step.

Comment: Then would, like @Bill Dubuque mentioned, observing that the difference between two consecutive elements is always $b$ (which follows from the construction of the set) suffice to state that, if $s>r$, then $s\ge r+b$ (as $r+b$ is the smallest element greater than $r$) and together with $s\ne r$, wouldn't this in turn determine the uniqueness of $r$ without making use of a contradiction?

Comment: Sure. You could say "since $|r-s|\geq b$ for all $s\in S\backslash \{r\}$, $r$ is the unique element of $S$ with 0\leq r<b$."

Answer (score 0):

We show here a direct proof of uniqueness.

In this exposition all numbers will belong to the ring of integers $\Bbb Z$,
 and three numbers $b, r, s \in \Bbb Z$ are related by
$\tag 1 b \ne 0$
$\tag 2 0 \le r \lt |b|$
$\tag 3 0 \le s \lt |b|$

The following can be proved without using reductio ad absurdum, and is left as an exercise.

$$\tag 4 r = nb + s \; \text{ If And Only If } \; [n = 0 \; \text{ and } \; r = s]$$

Now assume that

$$\tag 5 a=bq_1+r \text{ and } a = bq_2+s$$

is true.

Consider the statements

$$\tag 6 a+b=b(q_1+ 1) + r \text{ and } a+b = b(q_2+1)+s$$

$$\tag 7 a-b=b(q_1- 1) + r \text{ and } a-b = b(q_2-1)+s$$

Then the statements $\text{(5)-(7)}$ are all equivalent.

So we can construct a 'truth chain', to other statements

$$\tag 8 \hat a= b \hat{ q_1}+s \text{ and } \hat a = b \hat{ q_2}+s$$

and we can transform $q_1$ to $0$, so that $\hat{ q_1} = 0$ in $\text{(8)}$,

$$\tag 9 \hat a= r \text{ and } \hat a = b \hat{ q_2}+s$$

But then

$\tag {10} r = b\hat{ q_2}+s$ and by $\text{(4)}$, $\,r = s$ and $\hat{q_2} = 0$.

There are two ways you prove that $q_1 = q_2$:

Using $\text{(5)}$, $bq_1 = bq_2$ and $q_1 = q_2$ follows.

Since $\hat{ q_2} = \hat{ q_2}$ and the transforms $\text{(6)/(7)}$ are $\text{1:1}$ "on the q's", it must be true that $q_1 = q_2$.